# NumberFormatter not working correctly

Tags: ios, swift

I'm decoding a string version of a decimal that I want to be formatted and returned as a `Double`:

```
let str = "0.945404"
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
numberFormatter.roundingMode = .halfUp
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal

print(numberFormatter.number(from: str))
```

`numberFormatter.number(from: str)` seems to return `nil` and I can't figure out why.

Would love any help here. Thanks

Comment: It's working fine for me. It's returning an optional. I've unwrapped it with an `if let` and I get an NSNumber out of it. Have you done a project clean? Or what version of Xcode are you running?

Comment: What's the locale of the device/simulator running the code in the question? If your locale doesn't use the `.` as the decimal separator, you will get `nil`. And why are you setting `maximumFractionDigits`? That's only useful when converting a number to a string, not when parsing a string.

Comment: So it’s working in a simulator or on my device, I’m seeing a lot of my users getting nil. They must have Locales that use , as a decimal separator. I’m setting maximumFractionDigits because I want it to round to 2 decimal places

Comment: @ZackShapiro Where is the string coming from? Why does it use `.` in locales that use `,`? And the rounding only needs to be done when converting a number to a string, not when parsing the string.

Comment: The string comes from an API, it’s always formatted like 12.50 or 0.65. Never used a ,

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting a fixed format decimal string then you need to setup your number formatter with a matching locale. Without doing so the formatter assumes the user's locale and many locales do not use the `.` as the decimal separator.

There is also no need to set the fraction digits when converting a string to a number. Later, when displaying the number to a user you can use another number formatter (using the user's locale this time) with a desired number of fraction digits to get a displayable string.

```
let str = "0.945404"
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal

print(numberFormatter.number(from: str))
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI: This issue **only happened to me when testing on the device**, on the simulator the formatter was I guess picking up the US locale (Although i have localisation activated and it was meant to be German).